# Why did Schrödinger write a letter to Einstein “apologizing profusely for his duplicity”?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I’m reading “What is Real” by Adam Becker and this is mentioned without any more details. [Here is the excerpt](https://books.google.com/books?id=X4QqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT78&lpg=PT78&dq=schrodinger+apologized+to+einstein+for+his+duplicity&source=bl&ots=3c30bxaoz_&sig=ACfU3U2rwFRi-lk6bNb0wtSr4r57_mpNtw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC-J2c2sfiAhUYCTQIHWHDALEQ6AEwDHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=schrodinger%20apologized%20to%20einstein%20for%20his%20duplicity&f=false).

(It’s very possible that it refers to something that was mentioned earlier, which I missed - but I couldn’t find anything.)

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about the history of quantum mechanics but about history; cf. https://history.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walter J. Moore's [*Schrödinger: Life and Thought* p. 338](https://books.google.com/books?id=m-YF1glKWLoC&pg=PA338#v=onepage&q&f=false) quotes the 19 July 1939 letter, which explains why:

> I naturally knew there was a certain danger when I went back to Austria. But that the fortress would be surrendered without striking a blow, that I never reckoned until the end. Just a few days before, I was with a section chief in the Ministry and said to him: if you put a rifle in my hand I will be glad to defend myself, but don't let me remain as a hostage in nazified Graz. You can imagine with what feeling just a few weeks after the overthrow [*Umschmiss*] I read the signature of the same gentleman under the orders of the new Minister! I hope you have not seriously taken amiss my certainly quite cowardly statement afterwards. I *wanted* to remain free – and could not do so without great duplicity.